# Как получить файлы из папки с помошью google api v.3?

Tags: javascript, google-drive

Как получить список фалов в папке с помошью
Drive API v3 ?

[Метод с помощью которого этот список получается, но я не могу понять как вписать id папки](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22spaces%22%3A%22appDataFolder%2Cpictures%22%7D)